# How to convert a dictionary of contacts into a vcard (*.vcf file)?

Tags: python, vcf-vcard

I am working on some vcard files in python. I have parsed vcard file into a dictionary. Now I want to save it to a new vcf file after editing it. I couldn't find any solution to this. Is there any library or module which parse python dictionary in vcards ?

```
person = {'n': 'Forrest Gump',
          'fn': 'Forrest Gump', 'tel': '(111) 555-1212',
          'email': 'forrestgump@example.com',
          'photo': ';http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif',
          'adr': 'Kathmandu, Nepal'}
```

I want to get a vcf file like the following when I give this dictionary.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Gump;Forrest;;Mr.;
FN:Forrest Gump
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;VALUE=URI;TYPE=GIF:;http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Do you want to specifically turn dictionaries like this one (with these keys) into `.vcf` files, or *any* dictionary with valid `.vcf` attributes, including ones you didn't use or excluding some you did?

Comment: I want to convert any dictionaries with valid .vcf attributes.

Comment: I think in that case, the code I provided in my answer below should serve you well - please accept the answer, unless you have issues with it (and please comment on those issues there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably take a look at `vobject` here http://eventable.github.io/vobject/

```
import vobject

person = {'n': 'Forrest Gump',
          'fn': 'Forrest Gump', 'tel': '(111) 555-1212',
          'email': 'forrestgump@example.com',
          'photo': ';http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif',
          'adr': 'Kathmandu, Nepal'}

vcard = vobject.readOne('\n'.join([f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in person.items()]))
vcard.name = 'VCARD'
vcard.useBegin = True
vcard.prettyPrint()

with open('test.vcf', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write(vcard.serialize())
```

Note that writing the card without `.name` and `.useBegin` set will omit the `BEGIN` and `END` and the resulting file will not be a valid vCard. I'm not sure if there's a more convenient way to do this using this library, but you could simply create your own class that inherits from the existing one (or call the function from a new one) to clean up the code.